# svn create a new project under existing repository

Tags: svn

I have an existing svn repository, I managed to find the file with this:

```
<Location /svn/3rd-xyz/>
     DAV                svn
     SVNParentPath      /home/xyz/optdata/svn/storage/3rd-xyz/repository
     SVNListParentPath  On
     SVNAutoversioning  On
     SVNReposName       "svn"
     AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/xyz/optdata/svn/storage/3rd-xyz/conf/authz_congming
     AuthType           Basic
     AuthName           "3rdxyz Repository"
     AuthUserFile       /home/xyz/optdata/svn/storage/xyzconf/passwd.conf
     Require valid-user
</Location>
```

In Centos machine where svn server running, I found a directory as indicated by SVNParentPath above, and many projects under. I could see those projects in Windows tortoise client by: http://192.168.0.200:8082/svn/3rd-xyz.
I have googled to manage to create a new project say NewProjA. So I:

```
mkdir tmp;
cd tmp; 
mkdir -p NewProjA/trunk;
mkdir -p NewProjA/branches;
mkdir -p NewProjA/tags;
```

WHen I did:

`svn import . http://192.168.0.200:8082/svn/3rd-xyz  --message 'Initial` projectA'

I got:
svn: E170000: unknown URL scheme (...svn://，http://，file://)“http://192.168.0.200:8082/svn/3rd-xyz”

Having googled a while, unable to figure how to add a new project into existing repository. Please help. Thanks

Comment: I am in the linux SVN server box. have appropriate privileges. Windows tortoise client did not give me options under the  http://192.168.0.200:8082/svn/3rd-xyz

Comment: The "." is not needed and if you want to add a new project to the root directory of the repository "3rd-xyz" you should include the name of the project at the end of the URL as well. Otherwise all files will be added directly underneath the root directory.

Comment: @royaITS root directory? is it SVNParentPath   which is /home/xyz/optdata/svn/storage/3rd-xyz/repository/   or  /home/xyz/optdata/svn/storage/3rd-xyz/?